# Learning Programs Security in Solana

Tags: solana-program, program, spl-token-program, security, program-test

I'm looking at learning programs' security in solana. Was wondering if there was something equivalent to Ethernaut or Damn Vulnerable DeFi for Solana programs?

Appreciate any help, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a collection of resources with security related content (recommend any of the Sec3, Neodyme, Ottersec articles): https://github.com/0xsanny/solsec

You can also check out this repo with examples of common sealevel attacks: https://github.com/coral-xyz/sealevel-attacks/tree/master/programs

Module 7 of this course is based on the Anchor repo above: https://soldev.app/course